# making random colors in shapes on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a code for making random shapes on canvas.
i want to fill the shapes with random colors, for this i made this:

```
var R=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var G=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var B=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randColor='rgb(' + R +', ' + G + ',' + B +')';

    context.fillStyle=randColor;
```

I put this inside the functions that generats my shapes, but with no luck.
for the example, ive put it only in the makeRect function, but it should be in the makeCircle function too.
Can any one tell me what i made wrong here?

This is my HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
     <h4> Enter below, and then press the canvas to save your work</h4>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="750"></canvas>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>
    How many Circles do you want?
    <input id="inCircle" />
    </span>
  <br/>How many Squers do you want?
  <input id="inSquer" />
  <br/>
  <button id="creat">Creat My Work</button>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var drawing = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = drawing.getContext("2d");
var inSquer = document.getElementById("inSquer");
var inCircle = document.getElementById("inCircle");
var button = document.getElementById("creat");


button.addEventListener("click", function() {


  paint(parseInt(inSquer.value), parseInt(inCircle.value));
});

drawing.addEventListener("click", function() {
  saveImage();
});


function saveImage() {
  window.location = drawing.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
}

function paint(numOfRect, numOfCirc) {

  for (var makeIt = 0; makeIt < numOfRect; makeIt++) {
    makeRect(drawing, context);
    makeCircle(drawing, context);
  }
}

function makeCircle(drawing, context) {

  var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.fill();
}

function makeRect(drawing, context) {

  var w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

    var R=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var G=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var B=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randColor='rgb(' + R +', ' + G + ',' + B +')';

    context.fillStyle=randColor;

    /*context.fillStyle="green";*/
    context.fillRect(x, y, w, w);
}
```

And this is my css:

```
h4{
text-align: center;
}
#canvas{
    margin-left: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Comment: Voting to close / off topic / typo : "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting"

Comment: To the two people who answered it : please delete your answers, so that Gabriel can delete his question. All this has not any interest.

Comment: Five years on, I was fortunate to come upon this question which helped me solve a basic problem while learning JavaScript. I voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your first bit of JS was missing some brackets.

```
var R = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)),
    G = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)),
    B = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)),
    randColor = 'rgb(' + R + ', ' + G + ',' + B + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some brackets at

```
var R=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var G=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var B=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
```

put this for it to work

```
var R=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
var G=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
var B=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
```